# Services 3 and session authentication

Tags: 7, services, theming

I am creating a *titanium mobile app* that consumes and uses Drupal Services. I'm able to create a node but the user is always anonymous. I've tried setting the request headers so that the *Authentication* is basic.

```
authstr = 'Basic ' +Titanium.Utils.base64encode('admin'+':'+'password'); 
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authstr);  
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

For some reasons it still gives me;

> Code=3 "Authentication needed"

What is the best way to troubleshoot this? Is it even possible to use sessions in this manner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Session authentication is different than Basic authentication.

Session authentication requires that you login, by sending a POST request to ENDPOINT/user/login. It will return the session header information and you need to store that for future use and send it along with every request.

Comment: ok, got it, I'm abble to retried the session ID in the mannor, but how do I pass this along with subsequent requests? so I set the session ID as a request header, or pass it in the parameters of the JSON string.

Comment: You pass it as a header.

Comment: What is the appropriate header type to pass it along in  subsequent requests?

Answer (score 9):

Thank you very much for your help. I finally manage to autenticate and retrieve files from my rpc server. Here is my syntax in case anyone needs it.

```
// USER LOGIN
$authenticate = xmlrpc($settings['server'], Array('user.login' => array($settings['user'] , $settings['password']),));

// CREATE HEADERS
$options['headers']['Cookie'] = $authenticate['session_name'] . '=' . $authenticate['sessid'];

//RETRIEVE FILE
$file= xmlrpc($settings['server'], Array('file.retrieve' => Array(Array("fid"=>$fid),Array("file_contents"=> 'true'),Array("image_styles"=>'true') )),$options);
```

EDIT: AFTER SERVICES 3.5 you should do:

```
// USER LOGIN
$authenticate = xmlrpc($settings['server'], Array('user.login' => array($settings['user'] , $settings['password']),));

// CREATE HEADERS
$options['headers']['Cookie'] = $authenticate['session_name'] . '=' . $authenticate['sessid'];

// GET TOKEN
$token = xmlrpc(url($this->endpoint, array('absolute' => TRUE)), array('user.token' => array()), $this->headers);

//INSERT TOKEN INTO HEADERS
$options['headers']['X-CSRF-Token'] = $token['token'];

//RETRIEVE FILE
$file= xmlrpc($settings['server'], Array('file.retrieve' => Array(Array("fid"=>$fid),Array("file_contents"=> 'true'),Array("image_styles"=>'true') )),$options);
```

Comment: $settings['server'] is Drupal REST API Server or XMLRPC Server?

Comment: Hi AshwinP, it's the url of the XMLRPC server endpoint, something like http://www.acme.com/services/rpc. 
(I think REST authentication should be similar, but I never tried it)

Answer (score 0):

you can use services_basic_auth module (https://drupal.org/project/services_basic_auth) to enable basic authentication for drupal services module .

After installing services_basic_auth module you need to enable it by going to, Structure-->Services-->Edit

[image]

Now you can use Basic Authorization Header to create nodes.