# Exposed view filtering on a related node's value

Tags: views

I have a view with a list of nodes. Each node has a number of related nodes which I want to display below the parent node. This works fine.

However, when I go to filter the listing on values in one of the related nodes, then an empty set is returned.

I'm guessing it's trying to filter the parent nodes on this value, and not the related nodes. How can I remedy this?

Comment: I think I've just answered my own question. By checking 'Require this relationship' this solves the problem (I think).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025797/drupal-7-using-views-relationships-with-filters

Comment: :-) I think the recommended practice would be answer your own question so it does not appear in list of unanswered questions, just like I did here - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34274/unexpected-session-reset-when-making-authenticated-user-rest-requests-using-serv/34411#34411

Answer (score 1):

When adding a new relationship, ensure that you select 'Require this relationship'. Also, when adding a filter, ensure that you select the relevant relationship from the list where necessary.